# An unhandled exception occurred: error TS5024: Compiler option 'sourceMap' requires a value of type boolean

Tags: angular, angular-upgrade

I am updating my angular code version from 4.0.0 to latest. Instead of updating it all together from version 4.0.0 to 9.1.2, as a recommendation I tried doing it to version 6.0.0 first and then to 8.0.0 and finally to version 9.1.2. But while doing so following [this](https://medium.com/@pratik_m23/upgrading-angular-4-5-to-angular-6-9babee60cea6) link I first tried doing it to version 6.0.0. But somehow it updated packages to latest versions directly.
Now while running the command 'npm start' I am facing following issue :

> An unhandled exception occurred: error TS5024: Compiler option 'sourceMap' requires a value of type boolean.

and following error for ng serve command :

> Schema validation failed with the following errors:
>   Data path "" should have required property 'browserTarget'.

angular.json

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "sitc-web-app": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "assets": [
              "src/assets",
              "src/favicon.ico"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/assets/SHUI/shui-styles.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "src/assets/SH-HTML-CSS-LIBRARY/js/bundle.min.js",
              "src/assets/SH-HTML-CSS-LIBRARY/js/polyfills.min.js",
              "src/assets/SH-HTML-CSS-LIBRARY/js/vendors.min.js",
              "src/assets/SHUI/shui.min.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "local": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.ts"
                }
              ]
            },
            "dev": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.dev.ts"
                }
              ]
            },
            "staging": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.staging.ts"
                }
              ]
            },
            "production": {
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "local": {
              "browserTarget": "sitc-web-app:build"
            },
            "dev": {
              "browserTarget": "sitc-web-app:build:dev"
            },
            "staging": {
              "browserTarget": "sitc-web-app:build:staging"
            },
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "sitc-web-app:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "sitc-web-app:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "karmaConfig": "./karma.conf.js",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "src/assets/SH-HTML-CSS-LIBRARY/js/bundle.min.js",
              "src/assets/SH-HTML-CSS-LIBRARY/js/polyfills.min.js",
              "src/assets/SH-HTML-CSS-LIBRARY/js/vendors.min.js",
              "src/assets/SHUI/shui.min.js"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/assets/SHUI/shui-styles.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "assets": [
              "src/assets",
              "src/favicon.ico"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "sitc-web-app-e2e": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "./protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "sitc-web-app:serve"
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "sitc-web-app",
  "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "prefix": "app",
      "styleext": "css"
    },
    "@schematics/angular:directive": {
      "prefix": "app"
    }
  }
}
```

I separately added the 'local' part inside 'serve->configurations' and 'configurations' as I am running my code in local environment also.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "abc-web-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "XYZ",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve -o --configuration=local",
    "build-dev": "ng build --prod --configuration=dev --output-path=dist/dev",
    "build-staging": "ng build --prod --configuration=staging --output-path=dist/staging",
    "build-prod": "ng build --prod --configuration=prod --output-path=dist/prod",
    "build": "npm-run-all -p build-dev build-staging build-prod",
    "local-build-dev": "npm run build-dev && deleteAndCopy.bat dev",
    "local-build-staging": "npm run build-staging && deleteAndCopy.bat staging",
    "local-build-prod": "npm run build-prod && deleteAndCopy.bat prod",
    "local-build-all": "npm run local-build-dev && npm run local-build-staging && npm run local-build-prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^9.1.9",
    "@angular/common": "^9.1.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "^9.1.9",
    "@angular/core": "^9.1.9",
    "@angular/forms": "^9.1.9",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.16",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^9.1.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^9.1.9",
    "@angular/router": "^9.1.9",
    "angular2-csv": "^0.2.9",
    "auth0-js": "^9.13.2",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "jquery-datetimepicker": "^2.5.21",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.5",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
    "xml2js": "^0.4.23",
    "zone.js": "^0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "9.1.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^9.1.9",
    "@types/auth0-js": "^9.13.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.10",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.8",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.38",
    "@types/jwt-decode": "^2.2.1",
    "@types/node": "~14.0.6",
    "codelyzer": "^5.2.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.2",
    "karma": "~5.0.9",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^3.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.3.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.4",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.10.2",
    "tslint": "~6.1.2",
    "typescript": "3.9.3",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.901.7"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
    "lib": ["es2017", "dom"],
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "paths": {
      "@abc/models/*": ["app/models/*", "app/modules/booking-portal/models/*", "app/modules/training-portal/models/*"],
      "@abc/constants": ["app/constants"]
    }
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "preserveWhitespaces": false
  }
}
```

Kindly help. Any help towards a solution regarding this is highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.
In tsconfig.app.json file looked like :-

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "module": "es2015",
    "sourceMap": "true",
    "types": []
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

updated ***souceMap*** value to ***true*** instead of ***"true"***.